# permission_required not working on view

Tags: django

i have a problem about permissions on view of Django.

My code on view.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/kullaniciGirisi/')
@permission_required('reservationApp.change_reservation', login_url='/')
def rezervasyonDuzenle(request, id):
```

there are two app: App1: userLogin, App2: reservationApp

i assigned the permissions on userLogin and but i used permission_required on reservationApp

Assignments:

```
  username = request.POST['username']
  password = request.POST['password']
  user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
  pr = Permission.objects.get(codename='change_reservation')
  group = Group.objects.get(name='rol1')
  group.permissions.add(pr)
  userN = User.objects.get(username=username)
  userN.groups.add(group)
```

permission_required is not working, everytime it return to login_url :/
Do you have any idea about problem?

Comment: You can double check if the user/group has permissions are actually saved/correctly given in the admin or DB -  Just a suggestion

Comment: They are redirected to which `login_url`, and why do you have two different ones?

Comment: yes, the permissions are saved on DB and correct.

Comment: what do i use instead of login_url?

Answer (score 0):

If you're being redirected to `login_url`, either the user is not logged in, or the user doesn't have the permission `reservationApp.change_reservation`. Can you narrow down which of those is the case?

If you're not sure what's going on, remove the `@permission_required` decorator locally, and put this near the top (or just use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`).

```
def rezervasyonDuzenle(request, id):
    print request.user.is_authenticated()
    print request.user.user_permissions.all()
```

Comment: No, the user is logged in and that: @login_required(login_url='/kullaniciGirisi/')
@permission_required('reservationApp.change_reservation', login_url='/')   thanks

Comment: I cleared all permissions, users and groups, and i applied my commands again. The problem is solved. i think the problem is about tables of db.

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe logging in with super user. logout and login with another user and your problem might be solved. I had this problem and when I did that, solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your assignments,

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user:
    pr = Permission.objects.get(codename='change_reservation')
    group = Group.objects.get(name='rol1')
    group.permissions.add(pr)
    group.save()
    user.groups.add(group)
    user.save()
```

You need to save the changes, before anything.